# Java JCIFS how right to copy file from Samba to Windows local?

Tags: java, jsp, filesystems, samba, jcifs

I'm trying to create a Java application which can copy files from a Unix Samba share to a Windows folder. In order to achieve that, I'm using the  JCIFS library.

I have the following code:

```
SmbFile smbFromFile = new SmbFile("smb:////192.168.10.1//data", auth);
smbFromFile.copyTo(destinationFolder);
```

I'm modifying it to:

```
SmbFile smbFromFile = new SmbFile("smb:////192.168.10.1//data", auth);
SmbFile destinationFolder = new SmbFile("C:\\Temp\\IN\\");
smbFromFile.copyTo(destinationFolder);
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" jcifs.smb.SmbAuthException: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.checkStatus(SmbTransport.java:546)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:663)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.sessionSetup(SmbSession.java:390)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:218)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.treeConnect(SmbTree.java:176)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.doConnect(SmbFile.java:911)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect(SmbFile.java:957)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:880)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.copyTo(SmbFile.java:2303)
    at RU.Tasks.Task3_Load_MedioSCP_Tekelek_file_To_DB_Oracle_BMCDB.main(Task3.java:203)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

If I try to create a new file on the Samba share, it works as expected:

```
String user = "usersamba";
String pass ="1234";
String hostname = "192.168.10.1";
String sharedFolder = "data/new";
String path = "smb://"+hostname+"/"+sharedFolder+"/test.txt";
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("",user, pass);
SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(path,auth);
SmbFileOutputStream smbfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(smbFile);
smbfos.write("testing....and writing to a file".getBytes());
System.out.println("completed ...nice !");
```

Please help to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

option resolve to the problem

```
    InputStream in = null;
               OutputStream out = null;
               try{

                   String SambaURL= "smb://usersamba:1234@192.168.1.110/data/1b.csv";
                   File destinationFolder = new File("C:\\Temp\\IN\\");
                   SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS_");
                   File child = new File (destinationFolder+ "/" + fmt.format(new Date()) +"1b.csv");
                   SmbFile dir = new SmbFile(SambaURL);
                   SmbFile fileToGet=new SmbFile(SambaURL);
                   fileToGet.connect();

                   in = new BufferedInputStream(new SmbFileInputStream(fileToGet));
                   out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(child));

                   byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                   int len = 0; //Read length
                   while ((len = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
                             out.write(buffer, 0, len);
                   }
                   out.flush(); //The refresh buffer output stream
               }
               catch (Exception e) {
                   String msg = "The error occurred: " + e.getLocalizedMessage();
                   System.out.println(msg);
               }
               finally {
                   try {
                       if(out != null) {
                           out.close();
                       }
                       if(in != null) {
                           in.close();
                       }
                   }
                   catch (Exception e) {}
               }
```

[source here](http://www.programering.com/a/MTO2YTNwATM.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need the proper auth mechanisms. See for example:

```
private static void GetFiles() throws IOException {
    jcifs.Config.registerSmbURLHandler();

    NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(
            prop.getProperty("smbDomain"), prop.getProperty("smbUser"),
            prop.getProperty("smbPass"));


    StaticUserAuthenticator authS = new StaticUserAuthenticator(
            prop.getProperty("smbDomain"), prop.getProperty("smbUser"),
            prop.getProperty("smbPass"));

    FileSystemOptions opts = new FileSystemOptions();

    DefaultFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setUserAuthenticator(opts,
            authS);

    SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(prop.getProperty("smbURL"),auth);
    FileSystemManager fs = VFS.getManager();
    String[] files = smbFile.list();

    for(String file:files) {
        SmbFile remFile = new SmbFile(prop.getProperty("smbURL") + file, auth);
        SmbFileInputStream smbfos = new SmbFileInputStream(remFile);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] b = new byte[8192];  
        int n;  
        while ((n = smbfos.read(b)) > 0) {  
            out.write(b, 0, n);  
        }  
        smbfos.close();
        out.close(); 
    }

}
```